# How to modify a linux kernel to hide a process?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, kernel

I would like to be able to modify the Linux kernel, version 2.6.21.7, to implement a system call in order to be able to control visibility of a process, as shown below:

```
int hide(pid_t pid, int on)
```

- the parameter `pid` to the method `hide()` so that it would not be visible in the process table, displayed by `ps(1)`.

I've been told that it might be a good idea to add a member, which would indicate whether or not a task is "visible", to a structure `task_struct`, then proceed to add code to various places, including`fork.c` and `base.c`, which expose task information to `/proc` and so on.

Has anyone implemented this kind of process hiding in the kernel? What should I do to implement it?

Comment: What have you tried this far? Your idea of going into fork.c and base.c aren't completely off, but I think you should show some effort in form of code in your question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `make progress of the pid hidden`?

Comment: Why do you want to do so? It probably will break many things! Maybe it could disable `waitpid`, so your kernel will accumulate zombie processes... And it won't protect any secret: a motivated user would upgrade his Linux kernel to something more recent & reasonable. BTW 2.6.21.x is a really old kernel!

Comment: Linux already has the ability to hide processes and much more, check out SELinux.

Comment: if you are simply trying to obfuscate what is running, you can just make your child processes name similar/same to a known/trusted application.  `execl( "./ksyslog", "ksyslog", "someParameters", NULL );` where `ksyslog` is the name of *your* compiled binary child process.